# Is multipart copy really needed to revert an object to a prior version?

Tags: amazon-s3

For https://github.com/wlandau/gittargets/issues/6, I am trying to programmatically revert an object in an S3 bucket to an earlier version. From reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RestoringPreviousVersions.html, it looks like copying the object to itself (old version to current version) is recommended. However, I also read that there is a 5 GB limit for copying objects in S3. Does that limit apply to reverting an object to a previous version in the same bucket? A local download followed by a multi-part upload seems extremely inefficient for this use case.

Comment: From my reading, that 'Restoring previous versions' page doesn't recommend one option over the other at all. It's really going to be dependent on your use case. What are the expectations of your users? Do they expect to unwind all versions since the original version? What are their expectations if they delete this 'new' latest version of a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multi-part transfer request that transfers from S3 to S3.  It still takes time, but it doesn't require downloading the object's data and uploading it again, so in practice it tends to be considerably faster than other options:

```python
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('example-bucket')
bucket.copy(
    {
        'Bucket': 'example-bucket',
        'Key': 'test.dat',
        'VersionId': '0011223344',  # From previous call to bucket.object_versions
    },
    Key='test.dat',
)
```